# How to click a button on an external keyboard?

Tags: java, automation, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a keyboard that had programmable buttons and a specific button that changes the background color of the keyboard.

I would like to write a program that automatically triggers this event and on a loop, will change the background of the keyboard.

Is something like this possible with an external keyboard? It is a blackweb brand keyboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short of [rewiring the keyboard](https://cocasdaneve.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/custom-led-color-and-brightness-on-a-razer-blackwidow-ultimate/), unless there is software for your keyboard, you really can't achieve this. Most backlit keyboards receive power through USB and nothing more from the computer, that is to say they house their own circuits for color change and brightness making control via computer impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mousePress(int)). This enables you to simulate the press and release of keys, however I'm not sure if there is a specific name for this key(In Robot, keys are called things like `KeyeEvent.VK_2`(<kbd>2</kbd>), `KeyEvent.VK_S`(<kbd>S</kbd>), or `KeyEvent.VK_META`(<kbd>◆</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>⊞</kbd>, etc.), and I'm not sure what the name of your key is).

The following program would change the color every 5 seconds:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Robot r = null;
    try {
        r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {}
    for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++) { //execute 1000 times
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLORBUTTON);//press the button
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLORBUTTON);//release the button
        Thread.sleep(5000);//wait 5 seconds
    }
}
```

Obviously `KeyEvent.VK_COLORBUTTON` is not the name of the key, you will have to figure the name of that out yourself, and change it. If I do find out, I will be sure to edit my answer.

Comment: the key has no interface with the computer. This won't work.